# Is adding custom fields in OAuth access token consider a good practice?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, access-token

We're using oauth access token for a mobile app to communicate with our backend.

The simplified steps are:

1. User input PIN
2. FE send request to /oauth/token
3. /oauth/token verify pin and check 2 additional legal consent flags from legacies
4. /oauth/token cached the flags
5. /oauth/token return access token
6. FE check flag 1 and show 1st consent screen if the user hasn't accepted the 1st consent before
7. FE check flag 2 and show 2nd consent screen ''

The question is:
**Is adding additional logic to check for 2 flags in /oauth/token consider a good practice or not?**

Should we separate the logic to check for legal flags to another API calls from FE to make the /oauth/token more lean and maintainable?

I've tried to read through the Oauth standard and other practices but could not find any related to this.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth 2.0 is a protocol with a specific set of rules and its own terminology. If you wish to implement a solution that follows these rules, then I suggest that you have a look at "Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)". For more help, see https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/which-oauth-2-0-flow-should-i-use

**To your question**: You can add your own parameters to the flow as long as you provide the required parameters specified by OAuth 2.0.